# Which type of lock should I use to implement a cart?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm currently working on implementing a shopping cart feature for my e-commerce website. The current code reads a record from the product table, checks if the available quantity is greater than or equal to the requested quantity, and then reduces the quantity accordingly (i.e., new_quantity = available_quantity - requested_quantity).

The concern is when two transactions (let's call them T1 and T2) simultaneously read the initial quantity value (let's say 10). T1 requests 3 units, and T2 requests 8 units. If T1 reduces the quantity by 3 to get 7, T2, which has already read the old data, might set the new value to 2 (i.e., 10 - 8). How should I handle this concurrency issue to ensure accurate quantity updates in a scenario like this?

I came across a solution of using locks. But I am not sure if this would fix the issue. Is the lock type correct or should I be using some other lock. I am currently using this code code.

```
@Transactional
public void addToCart(CartDTO cartItem) throws Exception{
            
            Product product = entityManager.find(Product.class, cartItem.getProductId(), LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    
            if (product.getQuantity() >= cartItem.getQuantity()) {
    
                product.setQuantity(product.getQuantity() - cartItem.getQuantity());
    
                Cart newCartItem = new Cart();
                newCartItem.setCustomer(entityManager.find(Customer.class, cartItem.getCustomerId()));
                newCartItem.setProduct(product);
                newCartItem.setQuantity(cartItem.getQuantity());
    
                entityManager.persist(newCartItem);
            } 
            else {
                throw new Exception("Quantity in cart more that the available quantity.");
            }
        }
```

Will this be enough to handle the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `entityManager.find` is called with `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`, it tells the JPA provider to obtain a pessimistic write lock on the retrieved `Product` entity. This lock prevents other transactions from acquiring a write lock on the same data until the lock is released (the transaction is committed or rolled back).

So, in a scenario where two transactions (T1 and T2) are executing the `addToCart` method concurrently:

- If T1 reaches the line acquiring the pessimistic write lock first, it
  will obtain the lock, and T2 will be blocked if it attempts to
  acquire the lock on the same `Product` entity.
- If T2 reaches the line acquiring the pessimistic write lock first, it
  will obtain the lock, and T1 will be blocked if it attempts to
  acquire the lock on the same `Product` entity.

If conflicts are expected to be rare, you might consider using optimistic locking instead.

Optimistic locking can lead to better performance in scenarios where conflicts are rare. It avoids locking data during the transaction, allowing multiple transactions to read the same data simultaneously.

Comment: In my case, I am assuming that conflicts happen quite often. So I've implemented apessimistic lock. But is LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE enough? Is it still possible to have faulty data like I've mentioned in the description?

Comment: @TheBeast answer has been updated.

Comment: Understood. So if the second transaction tries to acquire the lock, will it throw an exception or will it wait for the lock to be released?

Comment: The second transaction will be blocked, waiting for the lock to be released by the first transaction.